How much latency is acceptable in an amplification system for singing?
I teach music in a public elementary school setting.  Many teachers (of subjects other than music) have an in-room amplification system.  They wear a microphone, the sound of their voice is amplified in a mounted speaker (either in the ceiling or wall-mounted).  The idea is that teachers won't tire their voices out so much having to speak loudly, and all students will have an easier time hearing the teacher.  Students who have a significant hearing difference carry a transmitter with them, which sends the teacher's voice to their in-ear hearing devices.
I am told that a similar device will be installed in the music room.  As I look over the specifications of the system, I expect that there will be some latency (lag) between my singing and the sound of my voice in the speaker.  So as I sing and play an acoustic piano, there will be a difference between when I hear the notes I play and when I/the students hear my voice.  My question is, how much lag will be noticable or annoying?
EDIT: I have discovered that the system will introduce approx. 25ms of latency.  I will update this with my experience once it is installed.

In my experience, in a large room, the room acoustics will matter much more. In an auditorium, there might be as much as 100 milliseconds lag between the stage and the rear seats. If echoes slap back from the back toward the front, the delay between original sound and echo in the middle will be even greater. And as they bounce all around, it can get muddy and impede understanding.

You wrote, "as I look over the specifications of the system, I expect that there will be some latency.". Why do you feel this way?  What did you see in the specifications that gave you this idea?  You've given us nothing to go on here.  Please revise the question with more details, otherwise I think the question should be closed as too vague.

@DataProcessing I feel that there will be some lag because it takes a non-zero amount of time for the signal to be processed and propagated to the speaker.  Is there a system that can do this with zero lag?

Analog systems are effectively 0, since electricity travels at the speed of light through the system.  There isn't any real "processing" to do.

@Edward sorry for the confusion.  This signal is digitally processed

I think you already got a decent answer below, I was just perplexed by what you saw in the specifications that made you think there would be a problem.  Even in sound reinforcement systems with 'high' latency (100ms or worse), you can quickly get used to the phenomenon.  Not something a professional performing musician would necessarily love, but it's amazing what our adaptive brains can do.

Around 10-12 ms seems to be universally accepted. However, another problem may be that those further from the speakers will have a greater latency than those using earpieces. Just something to consider...

@Edward Electrical signals actually do not propagate at the speed of light (according to this, it's about half the speed of light in air), but compared to human perception of sound, electrical signals are essentially instantaneous unless we're talking about extremely long distances.

@ToddWilcox I think that article has a lot more going on, he's talking about transmission lines and FR4 (fiberglass) using the 'good dielectric' equation, so likely much more to do with electric field propagation in transmission lines but I don't fully comprehend (I think I need to read the previous few chapters!!). The equation for velocity in a conductor is different (the 'good conductor' equation), and it would usually be quite a bit higher than half c, as far as I am aware, I think for practical purposes you can think of it as 'near c' until you get to systems on the limit of the physics..

@OwenM This Wikipedia page agrees that electrical signals do not propagate at the speed of light through copper conductors with typical insulators. Signal velocity is related to relative permittivity of the medium which depends on both the conductors and insulators involved. Although you're right that 50% of c is too low. Looks like signals propagate through common conductors closer to 70% - 90% of c.

@ToddWilcox Thanks! The stats on that wiki page are for significantly more complex cables (in construction and protocols they use, frequency of clock etc.) than a typical copper audio cable though. Going back to the first article and this wiki page (hehe, wiki page battles :D) the velocity would be fairly near c as copper's relative permittivity and relative magnetic permittivity are both very close to 1. (v=c/sqrt(1*1)) I'd say for a simple system at low speed and big copper wires 95% of c would be a safe estimate.

Yikes these comments have sort of gone off the rails...  the question is about how much latency would be annoying....

@nuggethead Haha yeah, fair point, I think we can agree that the analog portion would be fine! But the digital portion would probably be fine too, even the lowest-end of DAC's and ADC's needed to process the audio should be under the 'easily perceivable' threshold these days, even if it's not up to the standard of a recording studio low-latency setup, unless there's significant processing on the audio involved.

@ToddWilcox Actually, I take that last comment back, having looked into the equations a bit more thoroughly I agree with you, about 70-90% seems reasonable for a standard copper wire as well!

I belive this to be a very reasonable question. A badly configured USB interface can easily introduce audible latency and quite a lot of bluetooth speakers are completely unusable for live performances. Those are the components most people are familiar with. A well set-up PA system however will not introduce such latency. It can help however to position one self close to a speaker or have a dedicated monitor speaker so that the sound doesn't have to bounce from the back wall to get to your ears.

Pipe organists and un-mic'd singers in acoustically reverberant halls learn to deal with much larger latencies than 25 mS, as that's how long it takes sound to travel or reflect off the walls or ceilings in a room on the order of 10M in any dimension.

Can you get the sound of the piano into the system too?  This would help in two ways: 1. The timing of piano and voice from the speaker will be in synch 2. The students using the assistive devices will hear both.

Musicians can discern as little as 5ms (or perhaps 1ms for percussion?). Non-musicians will usually hear two distinct sounds if they are separated by at least 20-40ms, depending on the type of sound. This numbers are the results of studies of the precedence effect (AKA Haas effect).
The consequences of signal delays have been studied and more or less understood for at least 60 years. So sound amplification and transmission device designers are aware of this.
Analog electronic signal paths have such low latency that an amplified voice will come out of a PA speaker before the unamplified voice from the person talking reaches the same PA system through air (in other words, it's faster than the speed of sound).
Digital devices used to sometimes introduce noticeable latency during A/D and D/A conversion, but modern devices are usually much lower latency, under 1-10ms. This is usually not a problem at all.
Two things are more likely to cause problematic latency in modern systems:

High latency processing, such as pitch shifting or look-ahead dynamic control. This is less common and I doubt you have to worry about it.
Transmission of digital sound over a packet-switched network without a proper QoS configuration. This is also something you almost certainly don't have to worry about. This kind of thing crops up in large venues like stadiums, hotels, and convention centers.

My guessing you don't have to worry about those possibilities is that a public school is extremely unlikely to be able to afford the equipment or expertise to introduce those technologies to the school.

DId you notice the edit made to the question after you posted your answer? The system will introduce 25 ms latency, which seems like it would be problematic.

I suppose that would depend on the kind of music, but most amplification systems should not induce an amount of lag that matters. Such kind of lag should only happen with complex DSP chains or unstable transmitting channels, which should not be given in your case. Generally a noticeable lag should also be a problem with speaking, as you’ll hear yourself noticeably after you speak, which would be really hard to work with. So I’m positive that lag won’t be much of a problem for you. Rather you’ll need to test out if the system (which is most likely there for amplifying speech) will give you good acoustics with singing while playing piano.
For your question: I’d say if you are with in 20ms it should be okay. Depending on the music even more. You can simply test this yourself. Record some piano, record some singing and align them. Then try how much you can shift your vocals until it sounds off.
